# pygame keylogger improvement ideas?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygame

I'm currently writing a pygame keylogger based on the pygame event handler.
My old version was based on testing all available keys needed for my application but now, because of a huge loss of processing capacity in the old one, I have based it on retrieving the unprocessed information of the pressed key, searching for its place in the list, and making pygame put out its coherent string.
I have completed the first functional version and am open for some improvement ideas.

```
special = '''+#-.,´ß0987654321^<'''
konverted = '''*\'_:;`?=)(/&%$§"!°>'''
print(special, konverted)

def key_get():
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
         for i in range(0, 253, 1): #empirisch gemessen für 'ü' (letztes bei umlauten)
            if key[i]:
               name = pygame.key.name(i)

               mod = pygame.key.get_mods()
               if mod & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                  if all([str(x) != str(name) for x in special]):
                     name = name.upper()

                  elif any([str(y) == str(name) for y in special]):
                     for y  in range(0, len(special), 1):
                        if str(special[y])== str(name):
                           name = konverted[y]

      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:name = "mousebuttondown"
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:name = False
      elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE)
         pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean for us to do, but is this what you want?

```
for event in pygame.event.get()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        key_name = event.unicode
```

Comment: It doesn't differentiate tab and return but that's the least of my problems